# Value null at 'json key object' of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to parse this JSON:

```
{
  "data": [{
  "name": "Griya Legita",
  "is_broken": false,
  "is_repaired": false,
  "is_ok": true,
  "asset_parent": null
},
{
    "name": "4th Floor",
    "is_broken": true,
    "is_repaired": false,
    "is_ok": false,
    "asset_parent": {
      "name": "Buni Building",
      "is_broken": true,
      "is_repaired": false,
      "is_ok": false
    }
  }]
}
```

This JSON has a JSON object in a JSON array. But when I call the JSON object it says that it cannot be converted.

This is the code that I've tried:

```
class daftarAset extends AsyncTask < String, String, String > {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
      super.onPreExecute();
      pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
      pDialog.setMessage("LOADING...");
      pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
      pDialog.setCancelable(true);
      pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String...params) {
      String link_url = "https://example.com/api/assets";
      HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
      String json = sh.makeServiceCall(link_url);

      Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + json);
      if (json != null) {
        try {
          JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
          JSONArray data = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
          for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject ar = data.getJSONObject(i);
            String aset = ar.getString("name");

            JSONObject parent = ar.getJSONObject("asset_parent");
            String nama = parent.getString("name");
            HashMap map = new HashMap();
            map.put(in_aset, aset);
            map.put(in_ruang, nama);
            data_map.add(map);
          }
        } catch (final JSONException e) {
          Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
          getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
          });
        }
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            list = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.baik_list);
            adapter = new AssetsAdapter(getActivity(), data_map);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(list);

          }
        });
      }
      return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
      pDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

I don't know what's gone wrong in my code. I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm) and I feel like it must be correct but it has an error because the JSON cannot be converted.

This is my error:

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value null at asset_parent of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONObject
              at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
              at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:613)
              at com.mqa.android.monas.Fragment.BaikFragment$daftarAset.doInBackground(BaikFragment.java:188)
              at com.mqa.android.monas.Fragment.BaikFragment$daftarAset.doInBackground(BaikFragment.java:162)
              at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
              at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
              at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Add error log here?

Comment: yes, add error logcat here.

Comment: i'm sorry. i'm already add it now

Comment: make sure you response contain `JSONObject` at key `asset_parent`

Comment: i tought i already contain it. what i supposed to change? @AbuYousuf

Comment: print the response in `Logcat` and see it contain key `asset_parent` or not . as your indicate that

Comment: @MoNe your parsing is working fine with sample json you've provided. Please check the response you are receiving from server.

Comment: best way to debug your application and check the error, your parsing is perfect may be an issue with the response.

Comment: @SandeepParish `toString()` will return a `String`. and you are assigning `String` to a `JSONArray`

Comment: @SandeepParish you statement `JSONArray data = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data").toString();` will not compile .

Comment: OMG thank you guys. it must be because in my real json there is 'asset_parent' key that have an object and there are some of them also null. what do you guys this i should do to make it right?

Comment: Solved this yet?

Comment: actually not yet. because what it shows on my device is only the end of json repeatedly and not show the whole json with value of `name`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First make sure `JSONObject` contains `asset_parent` key and corresponding key value is not null. Then retrieve value from `JSONObject`.

Use this code :

```
      JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
      JSONArray data = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
      for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject ar = data.getJSONObject(i);
        String aset = ar.getString("name");

        HashMap map = new HashMap();
        map.put(in_aset, aset);

        if(ar.has("asset_parent") && !ar.isNull("asset_parent") ){
           JSONObject parent = ar.getJSONObject("asset_parent");
           String name = parent.getString("name");
            map.put(in_ruang, name );
        }else{
             map.put(in_ruang, null );
        }

         Log.i("Test", "Map: " + map.toString()); 
         data_map.add(map); 
          ................ 
          .............
      }
```

Hope it will solve your problem.
Let me know if your problem is solved.

Comment: it actualy works, but it only read one json object in many of it in array and show it in list repeatedly with same value. (i'm updated my actually json)

Comment: If will read all `JSONObject` for the key `asset_parent` which is exist and not null. What you want ?

Comment: i want it like if it's 'asset_parent' is null it only read name on it and only show 1 value. but if it not null it will read both of name on it and show 2 value. it actually show 2 value but only in one json `{ json.. }` in the end

Comment: Check my updated answer , update will store null if `asset_parent` is null else store its value and always store `name` value

Comment: is that key `name` or `nama` ? your provided example contains `name` and provided url contains `nama` ?

Comment: in my real code i add it `nama`. i'm just change a little to ask it here actually

Comment: yes it's `nama` actually, but i already change it to `nama` in my real code

Comment: I have printed the `map` in Logcat  inside the loop. check map building is ok. I think your adapter logic may be wrong

Comment: i'm added an image in question that shows in my device. i think the adapter must be right, right? because it can show the value but only the json in the end

Comment: fyi it show the same output when i remove `ar.has("asset_parent")`

Comment: all of name value

Answer (score 2):

**Try This**

```
if(mJsonObject.has("Data") && !mJsonObject.isNull("Data") ) {
  // code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a check whether the object is available or not like below

```
if(ar.optJSONObject("asset_parent")) {
   if(ar.getJSONObject("asset_parent") != null) {
       //process the object
   }
}
```

Comment: it says incompetible type in optJSONObject. it said required boolean

Comment: Check with "has method" like if(ar.has("asset_parent"))

Answer (score -1):

```
   public void get_user_details(){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest( Request.Method.GET,User_Details_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            Log.e("Response",""+response);
                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray user_holder = obj.getJSONArray("User_holder");
                            JSONObject user = user_holder.getJSONObject(0);
                            user_id=user.getString("id");
                            user_name=user.getString("user_name");
                            user_password=user.getString("user_password");
                            user_emailid=user.getString("user_email");
                            PreferenceUtils.saveEmail(user_emailid,Register_Page.this);
                            PreferenceUtils.saveUsername(user_name,Register_Page.this);
                            PreferenceUtils.savePassword(user_password,Register_Page.this);
                            PreferenceUtils.saveUserid(user_id,  Register_Page.this);
                            PreferenceUtils.saveLocalValue(localValue,  Register_Page.this);
                            sharedPreferences.writeLginStastu(true);
                            if(PreferenceUtils.getEmail(Register_Page.this)!=null || !PreferenceUtils.getEmail(Register_Page.this).equals("")){
                                startActivity(new Intent(Register_Page.this, CongoCoin.class));
                                sharedPreferences.writeLginStastu(true);
                                finish();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.e("User_json",""+e.toString());
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```